# Caffe matlab wrapper random outputs

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

I trained a CNN.
I used matcaffe to test it. My code is

```
data = ones(net.blobs('data').shape);
size(data)
net.blobs('data').set_data(data);
net.forward_prefilled();
prob = net.blobs('prob').get_data()
```

the results I am getting is (2 class classification),

```
0.0001    0.9999    0.0001    0.0000    0.9882    
0.9999    0.0001    0.9999    1.0000    0.0118
```

Why I am getting different results for the same input?

Comment: Share the model file too to get a more detailed idea on what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry i had some problems with the testing prototxt file. In the test prototxt file I had a learning rate. When I remove that I am getting the same results.